# C: Debugging options for gcc environments

Tags: c, debugging

I just started learning C, and I am looking for a simple tool for debugging in gcc environment. Such tool would print a stack trace, and indicate where a segmentation fault occurs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `gdb`; or a frontend like `ddd` or `kdgb`.

Compile with the `-g` flag.

Comment: gdb being text-based.  ddd being a GUI wrapper around gdb.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that should read, Compile with -ggdb3 flag.

Answer (score 1):

GDB does it all - you need to compile your program with debug information (use `-g` switch) and then open it with GDB. To print stack trace use command `bt`.

To investigate segfaults you need to pass path to core file to GDB as well, like this:

```
gdb yourprogram core
```

If your system by default doesn't generate core files in case of segfault, you can switch it on using command:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Answer (score 0):

GDB is what you are looking for. In particular, the backtrace command in GDB will show you a stack trace. http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

If you use X try "ddd"

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use the command line gdb, or one of the front-ends such as DDD, you should definitely take a look at the [gdb manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb_toc.html), which is also (like many GNU manuals) a very good tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I would also advise to look at [valgrind.](http://valgrind.org/)

There's also a nice integration of gdb in kdevelop (the emacs binding is fine too..)